# How to set default border in phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am using [phpspreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) for create excel in my system.
I want to set border color white for all sheets. I used below solutions but not working.

```php
$this->spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray(
    [
        'borders' => [
            'allBorders' => [
                'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
                'color' => ['rgb' => 'FFFFFF'],
            ],
        ]
    ]
);
```

```php
$this->spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getBorders()->applyFromArray([
    'allBorders' => [
        'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
        'color' => ['rgb' => 'FFFFFF'],
    ],
]);
```

I also used below solution but got error `Can only get pseudo-border for supervisor`.

```php
$this->spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getBorders()->getInside()->setBorderStyle(Border::BORDER_MEDIUM)
                ->getColor()->setRGB("FF0000");
```

Have any solution to solve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()
        ->getBorders()
        ->getTop()
        ->setBorderStyle(Border::BORDER_THIN)
        ->setColor(new Color('FFFFFF'));

    $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()
        ->getBorders()
        ->getBottom()
        ->setBorderStyle(Border::BORDER_THIN)
        ->setColor(new Color('FFFFFF'));

    $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()
        ->getBorders()
        ->getLeft()
        ->setBorderStyle(Border::BORDER_THIN)
        ->setColor(new Color('FFFFFF'));

    $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()
        ->getBorders()
        ->getRight()
        ->setBorderStyle(Border::BORDER_THIN)
        ->setColor(new Color('FFFFFF'));
```

i use this and work for me